# Comparing lists of different sizes and return an indices

Tags: python

I have 2 lists ...

The first is something like

```
a = [imgType_a, imgType_b, imgType_c]
```

The second is something like

```
b = [img_foo_a, img_foo_b, img_foo_c, img_bar_a, img_bar_b, img_bar_c]
```

I'd like to compare the lists and return a list of indices that correspond `a` where the last letter in `a` matches the last letter in `b`

For the example about I'd like to return ...

```
[0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]
```

if

```
a = [imgType_c, imgType_b, imgType_a]
```

and

```
b = [img_foo_a, img_foo_b, img_foo_c, img_bar_c, img_bar_a, img_bar_b, img_baz_a, img_qux_a]
```

the result would be

```
[2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2]
```

The length of the list `b` will always be `>=a`.

Comment: You want to match on the string values that those variable resolve to though right? It would be `'imgType_c'` rather than the variable name `imgType_c`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `index` to find the index of each element in `b` where it matches `a` (once you've converted those to be just the last letter). This can be done in a list comprehension:

```
>>> [[i[-1] for i in a].index(x) for x in [i[-1] for i in b]]
[0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]
```

Or, more efficient and clearer, convert your arrays first:

```
>>> a_last = [i[-1] for i in a]
>>> b_last = [i[-1] for i in b]
>>> [a_last.index(x) for x in b_last]
[0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a list, use a dictionary:

```
img_type_map = {img_type[-1]: i for i, img_type in enumerate(a)}
output = [img_type_map[img[-1]] for img in b]
```